Run process in background works from terminal but not from Vim
The following command:
xdg-open 'myfile.html' &

opens myfile.html in Chrome if I start the command from the terminal.
However, if I run :!xdg-open 'myfile.html' & from Vim nothing happens.
How to solve it? I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu 24.04 installed on it.

Works for without WSL. You may also want to follow all the leads in :help :!, e.g. the 'shell' and 'shellcmdflag' options. Can you give a minimal reproducible example? I.e. try without the quotes and the ampersand. Does that change anything?

Without the ampersand it just open chrome but it blocks vim.

But it does work in that case? I'm interested in seeing the shortest command that reproduces the issue. There's a lot going on in your simple command: single quotes, the amp to run it in the background and the magic xdg-open. Can you narrow down the problem?

Narrow down how? Can you write an example that I can just copy & paste?

I'd start with something as simple as :!cat /absolute/path/to/myfile.html and then gradually convert back to the original command. I'd also check :!env to see if the XDG_* variables are set. BTW, are you using Vim from terminal or gVim? Might also make a difference.

macOS: :!blocking-command & works here with vim --clean (and my full setup)

I tried with gvim --clean and :!xdg-open 'myfile.html' & works. There must be something weird in my setup. I also tried to run the same command from a terminal inside gvim and  it worked. Also :call job_start('xdg-open README.html) works. I'll stick with that.
